# Как обновить одну строку в терминале?

Tags: python, консоль

Пишу консольное приложение. Есть момент, где пользователю необходимо ждать. При этом показывается прогресс-бар с процентами. Дело в том, что сейчас это реализовано так:

```
print('Completed: '+percents)
```

И `print` печатает новую строку в терминале. А я хочу, что бы он обновлял эту строку в терминале, а не печатал `100` строк.

Если сделать так:

```
os.system('clear')
print('Completed: '+percents)
```

Соответственно, очиститься весь текст в терминале. Интересуют именно определенная строка.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: `print('\rCompleted: {}%'.format(percents), end='')`

Comment: перенеси ваш комментарий в ответы, чтобы я мог отметить его

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Text Progress Bar in the Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3173320/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

у функции `print()` есть аргумент `end`, позволяющий указать какой символ добавлять в конце строки - обычно это `'\n'`:

```
In [98]: print?
Docstring:
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

В вашем случае можно сделать так:

```
print('\rCompleted: {}%'.format(percents), end='')
```

или

```
print('Completed: {}%'.format(percents), end='\r')
```

`'\r'` - возврат каретки, т.е. печатать с начала текущей строки

Обратите внимание, что при печати следующей (новой) строки придется явно указать `'\n'`:

```
print('\n' + some_string)
```

или

```
print()
print(some_string)
```