# Удаление выведенного текста

Tags: python, windows, cmd, вывод

Я вывожу надпись "Нажмите любую клавишу...". После нажатия клавиши я хотел бы, чтобы эта надпись исчезла.
Покопавшись по форуму, не нашёл нормального и адекватного ответа, потому хочу получить помощь в отдельном вопросе.
Чтобы не было никаких вопросов привожу конкретику:

1. С возвратом каретки не совсем получилось по примеру из [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787253/Обновление-вывода-print-в-console-pycharm-Как-изменить-строку-вывода-10-после](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787253/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-print-%D0%B2-console-pycharm-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-10-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5). Нужен был другой, более конкретный пример, который мне дал в ответах ниже Pashok.
2. Не понятно, к чему была дана эта ссылка [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790239/Ввод-с-клавиатуры-не-приостанавливая-работу-программы-на-python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790239/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python). Никак применить данное не смог.
3. Вот отсюда [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744911/python-проверка-наличия-данных-в-sys-stdin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744911/python-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-sys-stdin) я смог только вытащить сам модуль msvcrt.
4. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704597/Параллельное-исполнение-двух-функций-python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704597/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-python) - пока с многопоточностью в Python не работаю. Рано мне ещё)))
5. Первая ссылка [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725081/cоздание-анимации-пишущей-машинки-c-обратным-процессом-в-python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725081/c%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-c-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-python) пригодилась, но в дальнейшем мне не удалось скомбинировать анимацию с кареткой. Т.к. дело моё, то считаю, что без этого можно обойтись. Собственно, в новом вопросе это не описываю.

Код моей текстовой игры работает в двух файлах: один функциональный, второй исполнительный.
Перед вами функция, которая выводит комментаторский текст, не являющийся речью персонажей.

```
def cnt(text, centers='center'):
    if centers == "left":
        print('{:<80}'.format(text), end='')
    elif centers == "right":
        print('{:>80}'.format(text), end='')
    elif centers == "center":
        print('{:^80}'.format(text), end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()

    sys.stdout.write('Нажмите Enter для продолжения...\r')
    while not msvcrt.kbhit():
        pass
    sys.stdout.write('                                \r')
    input()
```

Comment: @jfs, отредактировал.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Очистка консоли после каждого принта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715566/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я вывожу надпись "Нажмите любую клавишу...". После нажатия клавиши я хотел бы, чтобы эта надпись исчезла.

Чтобы ожидать любую клавишу на Windows, можно `msvcrt.getch()` использовать:

```
import msvcrt

text = "Нажмите любую клавишу..." 
print(text, end='', flush=True)
msvcrt.getch()
print('\b' * len(text) + ' ' * len(text), end='', flush=True)
```

Это стирает текст, печатая пробелы поверх него, если среда поддерживает `\b` управляющую последовательность. См. [Не работает цикл из itertools.cycle() использующий \b в PyCharm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705235/23044).

Обратите внимание, что `'\b' * len(text)` вместо `\r` использовано для случая, когда `text` не сначала строки печатается.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

Можно очищать консоль после нажатия кнопки.

```
>>> import os
>>> # Для windows:
>>> clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
>>> # Для linux / os x:
>>> clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
>>> clear()
```

Comment: В том-то и проблема, что удалить нужно только одну строку, которая содержит надпись "Нажмите любую клавишу..." Но ваш совет возьму на заметку. Есть место в коде, где это пригодится)

Answer (score 1):

Отдельно строку удалить не получиться её можно лишь изменить. Тогда, если вы хотите перезаписать свою последнюю строку, вам нужно добавить \r (возврат символа) и end = "", чтобы вы не переходили к следующей строке.
Допустим так.

```
 values = range(0, 101)
for i in values:
  print ("Complete: ", i, "%", end="\r")
print ("\n\r", end="")
```

Конечно можно попробовать и по-другому. К примеру так:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write('text1...\r')
sys.stdout.write('text2...\r')
sys.stdout.write('text3...\n')
```

Comment: Ага, т.е. курсор ввода возвращается на начало строки и новый текст пишется поверх старого, верно?)

Comment: Да, отличная версия, но я хотел бы, чтобы именно после НАЖАТИЯ клавиши эта строка перезаписывалась. Сделал следствие, что обычный input не работает, т.к. при нажатии на Enter происходит переход на новую строку.

Comment: По нажатию на клавишу? У вас это сервер?

Comment: О нет. Это текстовая игра. Переходы с главы на главу, с части на часть сопровождаются этой надписью) И по клику клавиши она должна исчезнуть. Как это сделать я уже решил. Ловите ссылку на код: http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1527502943/26e324ea/21905853.png

Comment: у вас случайно код похож на ответ MaxU? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/641166/23044

Comment: Если это переход с главы на главу, то, как мне кажется, будет приятнее для глаза воспринимать главу после полной очистки консоли) Так консоль не будет засоряться излишним текстом. А то что код похож, так это случайно получилось)