# как сделать удаление сообщения по таймеру? Питон

Tags: python, cmd, delete

Нужно, чтобы сообщение print удалялось спустя 2 секунды. Нужно для игры.

```
import time 
while t is not f:
   if f==1:
      print('1   2   3')
      time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Думаю [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596750/is-there-a-way-to-clear-your-printed-text-in-python) может быть ответом на ваш вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834311/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0?rq=1 посмотрите на эти ответы

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Timer

print("1 2 3", end='\r')
Timer(2, lambda: print("        ", end='\r')).start()
```